# Rascarse una pantorrilla contra otra

Tags: definiciones

> [Dioniso] sigue rascándose una pantorrilla contra otra, desesperado.

Entiendo que la pantorrilla es la parte de la pierna opuesta a la rodilla, la parte abultada. Entonces, ¿cómo es posible rascarse una a otra sin ser contorsionista?  Creo que no entiendo bien la palabra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La pantorrilla es la parte de detrás de la pierna, **justo por debajo del hueco de la rodilla**. Es una forma coloquial de llamar un conjunto de músculos que engloba los *gemelos* interno y externo (calf muscles) y el sóleo.

[image: Pantorrilla]

Sin ser un contorsionista, uno puede rascarse una pantorrilla contra la otra, incluso estando de pie. Hay que estar a la pata coja y pasar una pierna por detrás de la otra (aunque más bien frotas la parte de atrás de una pierna contra el lateral de otra, pero no tomes la expresión en el sentido más literal).

Comment: Ah, ya lo veo, gracias por la explicación.